# How to validate response data against Guzzle model structure?

Tags: php, guzzle

I've been using [Guzzle models](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/webservice-client/guzzle-service-descriptions.html#model-schema) with some success. Response data is unserialized just fine, and I can augment the data with other values not in the original JSON response.

However, all my models are missing their validation structure. I don't get any validation errors when I return unexpected keys or values of the wrong type. Either I'm doing something wrong or I misunderstand what's supposed to happen.

Here's my example code in the form of a test case:
https://gist.github.com/timwhitlock/8511971

Note particularly the last assertion. The lack of validation errors might be explained by the missing structure. But why is it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of Guzzle has answered my question via a Gist comment.
https://gist.github.com/timwhitlock/8511971#comment-990206

By default, response models are allowed to pick up additional (undeclared) properties in the response, but you can set `additionalProperties` to `false` to prevent it.

The original schema used to generate a response model is not present by default as most use-cases don't require it and it makes debugging messier when present.